# Open each link from array in new tab

Tags: jquery, tabs

I have an array like

myArray = ["http://www.google.co.uk", "http://www.ebay.co.uk"]

and I want to open them all in a new tab. The code I am using just puts all the urls together and tried to open it in one.

Any help greatly appreciated

```
  $.each(
                myArray,
                function( intIndex, objValue ){

                    window.open(myArray);
                }
                );
  })
```

Answer (score 2):

you are passing whole `myArray` to `window.open()`, you have to pass each item value.

change:

```
window.open(myArray);
```

to:

```
window.open(objValue);
```

Like this:

```
var myArray = ["http://www.google.co.uk", "http://www.ebay.co.uk"];

$.each(myArray,function (intIndex, objValue) {

    window.open(objValue);
});
```

### FIDDLE:

http://jsfiddle.net/ehsansajjad465/4jj9x3z5/

Answer (score 0):

The correct code is:

```
var myArray = ["http://www.google.co.uk", "http://www.ebay.co.uk"];
$(document).ready(function() {
$.each(
    myArray,
    function( intIndex, objValue ){
        window.open(objValue);
    });
});
```

You used the array variable in window.open, thats why it was joining the urls.